# Split string with potential removal of the first element

Tags: bash, bats-core

My goal is to split a string into an array and if the second parameter of the function is not 1, remove the first element of the array. Return string which could be literal for array assignment.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bats

log_debug() {
    echo "$@" >> /dev/stderr
}

split_line() {
    rmfirst=${2:-0}
    log_debug "args: \"$1\", ${rmfirst}"
    read -ra out_arr <<< "$1"
    log_debug "out: $(declare -p out_arr)"
    if [ $rmfirst -ne 1 ] ; then
        unset "out_arr[0]"
    fi
    echo "${out_arr[@]}"
}


@test "split line" {
    line_arr=("$(split_line "GETINFO version")")
    [ "${line_arr[0]}" = "version" ]
}

@test "split line rmfirst" {
    line_arr=("$(split_line "GETINFO version" 0)")
    [ "${line_arr[0]}" = "version" ]
}

@test "split line no-rmfirst" {
    IFS=" " line_arr=("$(split_line "GETINFO version" 1)")
    [[ "$(declare -p line_arr)" == 'declare -'[aA]* ]]
    log_debug "$(declare -p line_arr)"
    [[ "${line_arr[0]}" == "GETINFO" ]]
    [[ ${#line_arr} -eq 2 ]]
    [[ "${line_arr[1]}" == "version" ]]
}
```

but when I run the test fails:

```
 ✓ split line
 ✓ split line rmfirst
 ✗ split line no-rmfirst
   (in test file tests/foundational.bats, line 39)
     `[[ "${line_arr[0]}" == "GETINFO" ]]' failed
   args: "GETINFO version", 1
   out: declare -a out_arr=([0]="GETINFO" [1]="version")
   declare -a line_arr=([0]="GETINFO version")

3 tests, 1 failure
```

Any idea, what’s wrong with my function?

Comment: Please explain the problem in words, don't just dump code. What are you trying to accomplish, and what was your expected output?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Please [edit] your question to tell us what you need to do, don't make us have to try to figure it out by reading code that doesn't do whatever it is you want to do and don't add information in comments where it's easily missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove double quotes from `line_arr` to make it an array:

```
IFS=" " line_arr=($(split_line "GETINFO version" 1))
```